# How to merge two http post functions into one http post function angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in angularjs. Problem is i am sending some text to database from first function here

```
$scope.fn_PostStatus = function () {
    var param = {
        statusText: $scope.TxtStatus,
    };

    var Post = MediaService.Status(param);
    Post.then(function (msg) {
        $scope.UserData = msg.data.RMessage

        if (msg.data.RCode == 1) {
            window.location.href = '/Media/NewsFeed/';
        }
        else {
            if (msg.data.RCode == 2) {
                swal("Something went wrong please come back later.", msg.data.RMessage, "error")
            }
        }

    }, function (msg) {

    });
}
```

And I also want to send binary large object(Blob) to same URL where first function pointing
here is second function

```
 $scope.uploadme;
$scope.uploadImage = function () {
    var fd = new FormData();
    var imgBlob = dataURItoBlob($scope.uploadme);
    fd.append('file', imgBlob);
    $http.post(
        ServiceURL + "StatusPost",
        fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }
      )
      .success(function (response) {
          console.log('success', response);
      })
      .error(function (response) {
          console.log('error', response);
      });
}
```

Is it possible to merge both functions into one function and make just one http post request?

Comment: of course it is....assuming back end is set up to receive the new data property. Just use `fd.append()` to add more data to image upload one

Comment: I have tried everything that I Can. can you please elaborate in answer?

Comment: well for starters is your back end set up to receive this all as one?